# View commands queued in GNU at

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Is there a way to view the actual commands that have been scheduled to execute using the GNU **at** command? **atq** just gives the job ids and execution time, I need to see the command.

p.s. In my case the distro is Ubuntu

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After you check ID with atq, you can check the command with:

```
at -c ID
```

Also, as system administrator (root), you can check files in /var/spool/cron/atjobs/